# In monte-carlo tree search, do you propagate the result from the terminal or just the leaf?

Tags: algorithms, trees, monte-carlo

In most descriptions of monte-carlo tree search, I see the simulation step described as:

> Play out a game from the leaf node until a terminal node is reached and get the result.

And the backpropagation step is described as:

> Use the result of the simulation to update information in
> the nodes on the path from the leaf to root.

My question is, why not also update the nodes between the leaf node and the terminal, since the work's already been done? Is it incorrect to do so? And if not, when should you consider storing those results and when should you not?

Thanks!